# Django Check if Users are Logged In

Tags: python, django

To be clear, I'm not trying to check if the user is authenticated. On my app, I want users to be able to see whether other users they are friends with are currently logged in or not. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: you need to query the session model with database-backed sessions

Comment: Interesting question, but it would be good to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please check on this similar question. It might point you in the right direction.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096506/how-to-find-user-id-from-session-data-from-django-session-table

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure their sessions expire after they log out.

Then you need to query the django session model and to see who's online you need to match the friend with the session in the django session model

sorry not much help code wise