# How to decode this session data?

Tags: python, django, encryption, hash, base64

I have an old django application running and I'm trying to figure out how to parse a session object. Here is what I have thus far:

```
>>> import base64
>>> x = base64.b64decode(session_data)
>>> x
 '7489edf05bcdeae69f718ed7c809b32539646478:\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x12_auth_user_backendq\x02U)django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackendq\x03U\r_auth_user_idq\x04\x8a\x01\x01u.'
>>> x.split(':')[1]
'\x80\x02}q\x01(U\x12_auth_user_backendq\x02U)django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackendq\x03U\r_auth_user_idq\x04\x8a\x01\x01u.'
```

From this, how would I get the following decoded object:

```
{
    'auth_user_backend': 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'auth_user_id': 1,
}
```

My current approach was to do a regex, but that seems possible like the worst solution.

Note: I have manually tested every single solution on [how to find user id from session_data from django_session table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096506/how-to-find-user-id-from-session-data-from-django-session-table) and none of those work (most of them try and parse json, but even the above doesn't have a `{` in it.).

Comment: The second answer works for me if a make `x` a bytes object: just `pickle.loads(x)`. Furthermore `b64decode` returns a bytes object so I'm not sure what your example is doing.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I see -- that works. Want to post an answer and I'll go ahead and accept it? Actually for me it worked even without converting to bytes.

Comment: If you're using python2 that really needs to be one of the tags or at least mentioned in the question. I'll skip the answer, you can write it if you want to.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk sounds good, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk one question though: how could you tell that that was a pickled object with the leading `\x80\x02}` ?

Comment: I couldn't, but I looked at the questions and answers in the link you provided and thought that's what it probably was. Then I tested it and voila!